# Php codeigniter:Passing empty arguments through redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Here is my controller function

```
Class Customer Extends CI_controller{

 public function view($page='customer-new-bill',$param=null,$type='normal')
  {

  }
}
```

Sometimes i don't want have a value for `$param` argument so i just empty the second parameter using this way in redirect

```
redirect('customer/view/customer-view-invoice//invoice');
```

But it didn't worked.

I want to pass empty parameters through redirect is it possible?

**Note:**

I am used  this method `$this->view('','','invoice')` its worked but i need a `redirect`

Comment: try with $param=0 default  **0 as an empty integer**  if you pass it null your third parameter become second

Comment: Simple solution its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send the null parameters then send at the end

```
Class Customer Extends CI_controller{

   public function view($page='customer-new-bill',$type='normal', $param=null)
   {

   }
 }
```

and use this route

```
$route['customer/view/(.*)'] = "customer/view/$1/$2";
```

The route `(.*)` work for unlimited perimeters.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to have the **default** and **null** **parameters** at the end

```
Class Customer Extends CI_controller{

   public function view($page='customer-new-bill',$type='normal', $param=null)
   {

   }
 }
```

so now redirect

`redirect('customer/view/customer-view-invoice/invoice/');`

you can create routes too if you want

```
$route['customer/view/(:any)/(:any)'] = "customer/view/$1/$2";
$route['customer/view/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "customer/view/$1/$2/$3";
```